# My dataframe is not changed when I run for loop(comparing two dataframes)

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have two dataset, one with over 100,000 rows and 300 columns and the other with 200 rows and 6 columns.

I'm comparing these two datasets and updating df1 from df2 using for loop.

Here is the sample dataset

df1:

```
     KEY          MAIN_METHOD         DRUG_ETCDTL
0    100944       1                   unknown
1    67488        20                  unknown
2    101476       20                  unknown
3    102549       1                   sleepingpill_plunitrazeparm
4    103227       1                   some drug
```

df2:

```
     5. 방법/수단             Unnamed: 4
0    100944                sleepingpill_unknown
1    100984                others_green material
2    101476                others_anorexia
3    102549                sleepingpill_plunitrazeparm
4    103227                sleepingpill_pentobarbytal
```

and here is the code that I tried:

```
for i in range(0,4):
    index_key = df2['5. 방법/수단'][i]
    index_rawdata = df1.loc[df1['KEY']==index_key,'DRUG_ETCDTL'].index[0]
    method1 = df1['DRUG_ETCDTL'][index_rawdata]
    method2 = df1['METHOD_ETCDTL'][index_rawdata]

    # split df2
    mainmethod = df2['Unnamed: 4'].str.split('_',expland=False)
    mainmethod[i][0] = mainmethod[i][0].replace('sleepingpill','1').replace('others','20')
    # change the type so we can compare it with df1
    mainmethod[i][0] = int(mainmethod[i][0])

    if (mainmethod[i][1] == 1) & (df1['MAIN_METHOD'][index_rawdata] ==1 ):
    method1 = mainmethod[i][1]
    elif (mainmethod[i][1] == 20) & df1['MAIN_METHOD'][index_rawdata] == 20):
    method2 = mainmethodp[i][1]
```

so the df1 should be changed but when it use print df1 it is not changed.

The desired output is:

```
     KEY          MAIN_METHOD         DRUG_ETCDTL
0    100944       1                   unknown
1    67488.       20                  unknown
2    101476       20                  anorexia
3    102549       1                   plunitrazeparm
4    103227       1                   pentobarbytal
```

NOTE: I approached this for loop method since I didn't want to manipulate df2

Comment: (1) Fix the indentation of the code. (2) There is no "df1" but "df". (3) What should modify "df"? I don't see anything.

Comment: @MichaelButscher modified the code

Comment: This made things worse. Tr,y to create an [MRE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) (test it yourself) and explain which code should modify "df" or "df1".

Comment: all df are df1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To address the issue of the different column sizes, this solution manipulates the indexes of the two data frames before performing an update of `df1` using the [pandas.DataFrame.update()](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.update.html) method. The update method aligns the data frames using the index values and updates the values in columns with matching names.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df1 = pd.DataFrame({ 
    'KEY': [100944, 67488, 101476, 102549, 103227, 123456],
    'MAIN_METHOD': [1, 20, 20, 1, 1, 20],
    'DRUG_ETCDTL': ['unknown', 'unknown', 'unknown', 'sleepingpill_plunitrazeparm', 'some drug', 'something extra']
}, index=np.arange(111,117))

df2 = pd.DataFrame({
    '5. 방법/수단': [100944, 100984, 101476, 102549, 103227],
    'Unnamed: 4': ['sleepingpill_unknown', 'others_green material', 'others_anorexia', 'sleepingpill_plunitrazeparm', 'sleepingpill_pentobarbytal']
})

# make a temporary copy of 'df2'
tmp_df = df2[['5. 방법/수단', 'Unnamed: 4']].copy()
# rename columns
tmp_df.columns = ['KEY', 'METHOD_DRUG']
# split the string to get 'METHOD' and 'DRUG_ETCDTL' information
tmp_df[['METHOD','DRUG_ETCDTL']] = tmp_df['METHOD_DRUG'].str.split('_', expand=True)
# use a map to create 'MAIN_METHOD' column
method_map = { 'sleepingpill': 1, 'others': 20 }
tmp_df['MAIN_METHOD'] = tmp_df['METHOD'].map(method_map)
# drop all unwanted DataFrame columns
tmp_df.drop(['METHOD_DRUG', 'METHOD'], inplace=True, axis=1)
# make a copy of the index of df1
index_copy = df1.index.copy(dtype=type(df1.index[0]))
# make 'KEY' and 'MAIN_METHOD' columns the new index
df1.set_index(['KEY', 'MAIN_METHOD'], inplace=True, append=False, drop=True)
# create the same index for tmp_df
tmp_df.set_index(['KEY', 'MAIN_METHOD'], inplace=True, append=False, drop=True)
# update df1 with the values in df2
df1.update(tmp_df)
# restore the 'KEY' and 'MAIN_METHOD' columns in df1
df1.reset_index(inplace=True)
# restore the original index
df1.set_index(index_copy, inplace=True, append=False, drop=True)
# delete the temporary data frame
del tmp_df
# delete the copy of the df1 index
del index_copy
```

**ORIGINAL SOLUTION:** This works when there are the same number of columns in both data frames.

This solution avoids `for` loops and instead uses a temporary data frame to perform the task. The strings in the `Unnamed: 4` column are split using the [str.split()](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.split.html) function provided by Pandas. The `MAIN_METHOD` information is transformed using a [mapping](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.map.html). The `df1` data frame is conditionally updated using [numpy.where()](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.where.html) before the temporay data frame is deleted.

**EDIT:** The code has been modified to convert the temporary data frame column series to a numpy array using `.values` to avoid the error:

```
ValueError: Can only compare identically-labeled Series objects
```

Modified `np.where()` conditions:

```
df1['DRUG_ETCDTL'] = np.where(((df1['KEY']==tmp_df['KEY'].values) & 
                               (df1['MAIN_METHOD']==tmp_df['MAIN_METHOD'].values)),
                              tmp_df['DRUG_ETCDTL'],
                              df1['DRUG_ETCDTL'])
```

An alternative solution to avoiding the error would be to use `.equals()` instead of `==` when performing the comparison.

```
df1['DRUG_ETCDTL'] = np.where(((df1['KEY'].equals(tmp_df['KEY'])) & 
                               (df1['MAIN_METHOD'].equals(tmp_df['MAIN_METHOD']))),
                              tmp_df['DRUG_ETCDTL'],
                              df1['DRUG_ETCDTL'])
```

Original code:

```py
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df1 = pd.DataFrame({ 
    'KEY': [100944, 67488, 101476, 102549, 103227],
    'MAIN_METHOD': [1, 20, 20, 1, 1],
    'DRUG_ETCDTL': ['unknown', 'unknown', 'unknown', 'sleepingpill_plunitrazeparm', 'some drug']
}, index=np.arange(11,16))

df2 = pd.DataFrame({
    '5. 방법/수단': [100944, 100984, 101476, 102549, 103227],
    'Unnamed: 4': ['sleepingpill_unknown', 'others_green material', 'others_anorexia', 'sleepingpill_plunitrazeparm', 'sleepingpill_pentobarbytal']
})

# make a temporary copy of 'df2'
tmp_df = df2[['5. 방법/수단', 'Unnamed: 4']].copy()
# rename columns
tmp_df.columns = ['KEY', 'METHOD_DRUG']
# split the string to get 'METHOD' and 'DRUG_ETCDTL' information
tmp_df[['METHOD', 'DRUG_ETCDTL']] = tmp_df['METHOD_DRUG'].str.split('_', expand=True)
# use a mapping to create 'MAIN_METHOD' column
method_map = { 'sleepingpill': 1, 'others': 20 }
tmp_df['MAIN_METHOD'] = tmp_df['METHOD'].map(method_map)
# drop unwanted columns (This step is optional)
tmp_df.drop(['METHOD_DRUG', 'METHOD'], inplace=True, axis=1)
# update 'df1'
df1['DRUG_ETCDTL'] = np.where(((df1['KEY']==tmp_df['KEY'].values) & 
                               (df1['MAIN_METHOD']==tmp_df['MAIN_METHOD'].values)),
                              tmp_df['DRUG_ETCDTL'],
                              df1['DRUG_ETCDTL'])
# delete temporary copy of 'df2'
del tmp_df
```

Comment: since df1 has more columns than df2, `ValueError: Can only compare identically-labeled Series objects` occurred. what can I do?

Comment: np.where method caused the error

Comment: I've updated the provided solution to handle the error.

Comment: ValueError: ('Lengths must match to compare', (104959,), (121,)) occurred. two dataframes don't have same rows and I think that's why

Comment: I've added a solution that updates `df1` after creating matching indexes in the data frames.

Comment: What do I do if I want to allocate `tmp_df['DRUG_ETCDTL']` depending on `tmp_df['MAIN_METHOD']`? `if df['MAIN_METHOD'] == 1 & tmp_df['MAIN_METHOD'] == 1 then allocate tmp_df['DRUG_ETCDTL'] to df['DRUG_ETCDTL']`, but `if df['MAIN_METHOD'] == 20 & tmp_df['MAIN_METHOD'] == 20 then allocate tmp_df['DRUG_ETCDTL'] to df['METHOD_ETCDTL']`.

Comment: nvm, I solved it